# C# What does a lambda that points to a new anonymous type mean?

Tags: c#

I have used lambdas in the past with LINQ and making anonymous functions, but the following line has me confused.

```
(a,b) => new {a, b.PropertyA, b.PropertyB, b.PropertyC }
```

What is going on here? It looks like anonymous method is pointing an anonymous type. This is being passed in as the "resultSelector" argument to a Join method.

Comment: Your question already contains its own answer.  There is nothing left to answer.

Comment: It is an anonymous method that returns an anonymous type, it doesn't point to it, it returns it. Imagine the word "return" in front of the `new`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at it in the larger context.  We've got a table of customers and a table of orders, where each customer has an integer ID and each order has the ID of the customer who did the ordering. We want all the customers with the amounts of all their orders:

```
var results = customers.Join(
  orders,
  customer => customer.Id,
  order => order.CustomerId,
  (customer, order) => new {customer, order.Amount});
```

The compiler will translate that into:

```
IEnumerable<SomeAnonType<Customer, decimal>> results = 
  Enumerable.Join<Customer, Order, int, SomeAnonType<Customer, decimal>>(
    customers,
    orders,
    (Customer customer) => { return customer.Id; },
    (Order order) => { return order.CustomerId; },
    (Customer customer, Order order) => { return new {customer, order.Amount};} );
```

`Join` will enumerate all the customers and all the orders, fetching their ids based on the first two lambdas, and build a collection of (customer, order) pairs where the ids match.  Then it will iterate over the collection of pairs and pass them to the third lambda to produce a sequence of objects of anonymous type.

Is that now clear? Or do you need more explanation of what is going on here?

**Exercise**: Suppose `Order.CustomerId` is of type `int?`, not `int`.  Should that be an error?  Or should C# figure that if `Customer.Id` is `int` and `Order.CustomerId` is `int?` then the user probably meant "treat the `int` as `int?`"?    Suppose you did a join where the join keys were of type `Giraffe` and `Turtle`.  Should type inference assume that you meant `Animal`, or should it give an error saying that it is unclear which type was intended? This was one of many subtle questions that we pondered when designing and implementing type inference in C# 3, and it only got harder when I added generic variance in C# 4! See if you can work it out.

Comment: That clears things up. Thank you. As for the exercise... I am going to take a wild guess. In the first instance, I would think C# would treat that similar to how SQL treats it when you joining on a column with a null value. In the second instance, maybe it would fall back to an "equals" method in Animal (provided Turtle or Giraffe haven't overridden it)? Looks like I should spend some time playing / experimenting over the weekend.

Comment: @Dave: If this subject -- generic type inference on complicated methods like Join -- interests you I have written many articles about it over the years both on my original msdn blog and on ericlippert.com.

Answer (score 1):

The specified code represents a function taking two parameters and when invoked will create a new anonymous type with the specified properties.

So, this:

`(a,b)` represents the parameters.

and this:

```
new {a, b.PropertyA, b.PropertyB, b.PropertyC }
```

is the code to be executed.